# How to save recorded audio file on server automatically in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, audio

I am developing a project in `ASP.NET MVC 4`. I am using `recorder.js` to record an audio. It is recording fine on `chrome`.

On clicking download link the recorded audio file downloads on local machine in Downloads folder but I need to save that recorded audio file on server automatically when recording stops. I am stopping the recording after 10 seconds.

Here is my code for downloading the recorded audio file:

```
function downloads() {
    var url = $('#recorded-audio').attr('src');
    if (typeof url != 'undefined') {
        var link = window.document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = 'RecordedFile.wav';
        var click = document.createEvent("Event");
        click.initEvent("click", true, true);
        link.dispatchEvent(click);
    }
    else {
        alert("First Record Audio");
    }
}

<a href="#" onclick="downloads();">download</a>
```

**How can I save the recorded file on server without clicking on link and save it on server automatically?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with recorder.js but you can't automatically pull a file off of someones machine.  This is a security feature; imagine if you went to some page and with some JavaScript someone could just start pulling files off of your machine.

Unless recorder.js is storing the recording in memory you have no recourse to accomplish what you want.  If it is then you could send the completed stream back to the server as a byte array.